# Choppy video in Pitivi

Tags: pitivi

I am trying to edit 720p mov video footage in Pitivi, and when I place 1 clip in the timeline it plays fine in realtime. The problem begins when I add another clip and try to edit. Besides the 1st clip (that continues to run in realtime), all the other clips or cuts are choppy. I currently have 3gigs of ram and an Intel duo core processor. And using 10.10.
Is there something I can try? I've heard of Kdenlive, is it better that Pitivi in handling 720p footage?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you should report a bug. To do so press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `ubuntu-bug pitivi`.

Comment: Now that I know how to do it, I will report it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [LiVES](http://lives.sourceforge.net/).

It has been packaged for Ubuntu; you can install it by clicking this link:
[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: It would be nice if people giving -1 would provide the reason, that is  how the downvote is expected to be used. The last part on the question asks for alternatives to Pitivi.